# Maven how to force to includes all compilation error .class in target .jar

Tags: java, maven, build, jar

---

### My problem

I am using maven to build a target .jar.

- If i build the project and some .java file have a compilation error, then maven will automatically exclude those files from the .jar.
- I have setup maven to not fail the build on error and a .jar file is generated always.

```
mvn -jar:jar install
```

---

### My question

- For test purpose, i would like to be able to include all .class in the target .jar even if some .class have a compilation error. How should it be done ?

Comment: I have answered a lot of Maven questions here on SO, and I know that many people who ask "How do I do X?" should just _not_ do X, but try to solve the original problem in the Maven way. So my first attempt when people ask something highly unusual is to find out what is behind that question.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want the jar to include a `.class` file even if you got a compiler error when generating that particular `.class` file?

Comment: @JF Meier , yes this is correct. Basically i got two jar referencing each other and i do not want to solve a cyclic dependency yet. The error is related to the fact that JAR A cannot find the package in JAR B since it is not yet compiled. For instance the error is [ERROR] /C:/project/TheClass.java:[3,44] package external.package.theotherclass does not exist

Comment: My answer and my first comment got deleted. I somehow understand that, in the strict sense, my answer did not answer the question. So let met add the main points as a comment: Tidying up a cyclic dependency is usually relatively straightforward. Trying to build an application with compilation errors and somehow make it work is really risky. So I would advice anybody reading this to _not_ try to trick the compiler, but instead correct the original errors.

Comment: @JF meier fine but the question remain the same, how in maven do you force compilation error class to be included in a target .jar ? This is the main purpose of this thread. I guess for other case mostly quick test, you might find useful to do a first jar to check if everything behave properly before refactoring a big bunch of code to remove a cyclic dependency and i think its very understandable. I didn't ask opinion if its right or not, else i would have asked the question in another way. You have warned everyone, obviously everyone knows that already. Let's answer the original question now.

Comment: Probably you have to add to your question what Java compiler you want to use. Since you want the compiler to somehow ignore/repair the error while creating the `.class` file, instead of just creating a some garbage, this may be relevant information.

Comment: In eclipse you can create a JAR with all class included Right Click project > export > JAR. I don't think knowing the java compiler will help. My question is related to MAVEN, obviously maven is removing failing class and configuration has to be done in Maven.

Comment: That is not obvious to me.  Eclipse has its own compiler. The difference may be due to the compiler. My best approach would be to go through all the options of your compiler.

Comment: your answer is not relevant to maven, the configuration must be done in maven.

Comment: You can pass compiler options from Maven. But you need to know which compiler options you need.

Comment: @JF Meier, thank you for your answer. I checked a bit and yes, you are right it needs to add a compiler option. It might needs to be added in maven under the  compiler plugin. I checked in eclipse when you do a Right click project > export, it ask for option such as do you want to "export class files with compile errors". i guess eclipse is using an option at compilation when you select this option. I am now checking what might be this option.

Comment: @JF Meier, actually i just verified my maven build and if one class fail it does not include any class at all even the one compiling successful, i also forced to not fail on build error. It is worst than expected. Fine if maven wants to not include failing class but removing clean class, is insane. What might be the maven configuration to not exclude successful class ?

Comment: There is another way to do it, just create both jar in with eclipse then reference them in maven with scope = system and referencepath =  C:/fullpath. Build once your project successfully. Then remove for both the scrope = system and referencepath, and replace with scope = compile. Clean and rebuild your project it will work perfectly. It is one way to do it.

Comment: as well a CYCLIC REFERENCE IS NOT ALWAYS A BAD THING. For instance in this precise case a project UTIL to create MOCK object is using another project UTIL for JSE as a JAR. but a cyclic dependence exist when the JSE project do unit test using the  project UTIL MOCK and the project MOCK use some class from the project JSE to create MOCK objects. In this case i don't see any problem at tricking the Maven to build your project. So think twice on what purpose is behind the cyclic reference.

Comment: In my opinion, a cyclic dependency is _always_ a bad thing. You need to build projects in the order they depend on each other. If you have a cyclic dependency, this is not possible. On the other hand, if two projects depend on each other, why not just merge them?

Comment: And furthermore, when I tried to "trick" Maven, Maven fought back. If you leave the standard, you are on your own. Don't be surprised if some Maven plugin or IDE integration breaks in some unexpected ways.

Comment: i can live with that :)

Comment: I think you are right, merging the two projects will work fine. I think it is not a architecture fault to have one jar for mock and another one for jse util. And it does not make sense to refactor the two projects or to merge them. I see it more like a limitation of the project. If we think about it, why a cyclic reference is working fine if both project are merged as one project and why it won't work if they are separated think about it ? I don't consider my issue as a case of wrong implementation. But i believe in most cases cyclic references are wrong. My case is a bit different.

Comment: as well i don't have a class A that use a class B and reverse Class B using class A. I just have a JAR used for test purpose, used by almost all my projects. And to make the code clean and efficient this test JAR is using another JSE common JAR. Unfortunately this JSE common JAR needs test and uses the test JAR. But no where in my code i got a class referencing another class in a cyclic way. This is why two jar working together SHOULD WORK. It is a limitation of the framework. cyclic reference between two JAR because we reference a jar that is not yet built should WORK.

Comment: Again, I totally agree with you a true cyclic reference of code is wrong (2 class referencing each others) . Now referencing a package is not a cyclic issue. the proof is again if the project is merged it works !